# Formula needed to automatically generate 14 days from entered date

Tags: excel

I am creating a chart where one column has date 1/14/15 and I need the next column to read 2 weeks (or 14 days) after that date. What fourmula wuold I use? Thanks

Comment: If date is in `A1`, just use `=A1+14`. It will add days by default and will format the output as a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date values, you can simply use arithmetic with day value to get new date.  So if cell A1 has your date, then you can use =A1+14 to get 14 days after the date.

Ref: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926?CorrelationId=98e31a1a-2c82-4522-b7dc-f4e26b562cfb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thank you very much - I was able to successfully apply the formula. Thanks again. Happy FRIDAY.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.  If I helped you, be sure to mark the answer as correct :)